# populate new records in plsql table of records in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table of records in plsql.

step 1. populate the table with following:

```
                   select 1, oeh.header_id oeh.order_number, 'This is step 1' BULK COLLECT
               into l_stat_tab
               from oe_order_headers_all oeh
               where oeh.header_id = 7923374;

test_record.get_jobs_stat( l_stat_tab);
```

Step 2: in the same procedure, I need this again to populate the record:

```
              select 2, header_id, order_number,'This is step 2' BULK COLLECT
               into l_stat_tab
               from order_table
               where id = 7923373;

test_record.get_jobs_stat( l_stat_tab);
```

for the next call, the values of first call is replaced.

how can I found the next available index or I can insert (populate) in table of records?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_record
            AS
               TYPE jobs_stat_t IS RECORD (
                  valid                NUMBER,
                  header_id            NUMBER,
                  child_header_id      NUMBER,
                  order_number         NUMBER,
                  line_number          NUMBER,
                  parent_line_number   NUMBER,
                  wip_entity_id        NUMBER,
                  status_type          VARCHAR2 (30),
                  ordered_item         VARCHAR2 (50),
                  remarks              VARCHAR2 (100)
               );

               TYPE jobs_stat_table_t IS TABLE OF jobs_stat_t
                  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

               PROCEDURE get_jobs_stat (
                  p_jobs_stat_table   IN   jobs_stat_table_t
               );
            END test_record;
```

Comment: l_stat_tab  can you give the type definition for this?

Comment: create or replace PACKAGE test_record AS
    type jobs_stat_t is record (
  valid number, header_id number , child_header_id number, order_number number, line_number number, parent_line_number number, wip_entity_id number, status_type varchar2(30), ordered_item varchar2(50), remarks varchar2(100)
 );

   type jobs_stat_table_t is table of jobs_stat_t index by binary_integer;

    procedure get_jobs_stat(p_jobs_stat_table in jobs_stat_table_t);
      
   END test_record;

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will be correct for you, but for example, it is possible to make like this:

```
WITH sel AS (
select 1, oeh.header_id oeh.order_number, 'This is step 1' 
from oe_order_headers_all oeh
where oeh.header_id = 7923374
UNION ALL
select 2, oeh.header_id, oeh.order_number,'This is step 2' 
from oe_order_headers_all oeh
where oeh.header_id = 7923373)

SELECT *
BULK COLLECT
into l_stat_tab
FROM sel;
```

Or you can use `MULTISET UNION`, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444234/concatenating-collections-in-plsql) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/o53plsql-083350.html)

Comment: I don't need to union the 2 queries, my requirement is: in the same procedure, I need to insert / populate records, from different queries in pl sql table.

Comment: Check MULTISET UNION

Comment: I don't need to union, these 2 queries, may be I am unable to explain the requirement: for example, I have a procedure from where on line no 10, I will call the said procedure to populate the records, then on line no 20, I again need to call the procedure to populate the records. in this way I want these all records to be available in my record table.